# Yet Another "Connection Timeout Expired pre-handshake acknowledgement" problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

This is SQL Server 2012SP4 on Windows 2012R2, with .NET Framework 4.7.02053.

I've RDPed into the database VM and open SSMS.

- It times out with this error the first time I try to connect.
- If I try again, it works.
- If I increase the connection timeout, it works.

But why is it happening locally?  This migrated from SQL Server 2008 and Windows 2008R2 and did not have this problem.  Since a canned application that can't specify the connection timeout is failing, we need to solve this.

IPv6 is disabled both at the Windows level and in SQL Server Config Manager.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting with AD creds? Maybe you have a delay going to the AD server for Authentication. On the 2nd attempt the authentication is cached on the local server.

Comment: @JasonBluefire it happens both with AD and SQL Server authentication, using IP addresses and names.

Comment: Interesting. You covered most anything else I can think of. Hopefully, someone else chimes in. I have to ask though, does the server have adequate resources? Is the RAM, CPU, or Disk IO tapped out? Same thing for the VM host.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server? Is it *express* edition by chance or are any of the databases set for auto_close?